# UPDATE БД и переоформление вывода без перезагрузки

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Есть страница, на которой выводятся записи с помощью из БД с помощью такого вот запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM base WHERE Status < 2 ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

И у каждой записи есть кпопка удаления:

`<div id="4">Удалить</div>`(id уникальный под каждую запись)

Можно ли как-то при нажатии на этот `<div>` получать его `id` и использовать для того, чтобы обновить БД таким запросом:

```
UPDATE base SET Status='2' WHERE id = divID
```

Я знаю, что это можно делать во внешнем `PHP` скрипте.

А можно ли делать это без перезагрузки страницы? Обновлять БД и обновлять данные на странице снова сделав запрос к БД и выведя ответ(он уже будет без этой записи).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понял вам нужно что то подобное:
Для работы скрипта нужны два файла index.php и query.php
Код страницы index.php

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#id_delete_div').click(function(){
            setVote('delete', $(this));
        });
    });
    // element - кнопка, по которой кликнули
    function setVote(type, element){
        // получение данных из поля
        var id_rec = element.parent().find('#id_rec').val();
var type='delete';
        $.ajax({
            // метод отправки 
            type: "POST",
            // путь до скрипта-обработчика
            url: "query.php",
            // какие данные будут переданы
            data: {
                "id_rec": id_rec,
                "type": type
            },
            // тип передачи данных
            dataType: "json",
            // действие, при ответе с сервера
            success: function(data){
                // в случае, когда пришло success. Отработало без ошибок
                if(data.result == "success"){   
                    alert('Удалено');
$(body).emty();
$(body).load('query_upd.php');
                }else{
                    // вывод сообщения об ошибке
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php
        $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'arenda');
        if($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM records WHERE number > 2 ORDER BY `id` DESC")){
        while($set = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id = $set['id']; //поле из БД которое выводит ID
    echo '<div id="id_delete_div">Ваш ID='.$id.'<a href="" id="delete">Удалить</a><input id="id_rec" type="hidden" value="'.$id.'"></div>';
        }
        }
        ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Код страницы query.php

```
 <?php

// подключение к бд
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'arenda');    
// контейнер для ошибок 
$error = false;
// получение данных

$idrec=  $_POST['id_rec'];


if(mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE records SET number='1' WHERE id = '$idrec'")){

}
else{
$error = 'Ошибка при выполнении запроса';
}
// делаем ответ для клиента
if($error){
    // если есть ошибки то отправляем ошибку и ее текст
    echo json_encode(array('result' => 'error', 'msg' => $error));
}else{
    // если нет ошибок сообщаем об успехе
    echo json_encode(array('result' => 'success'));
}
?>
```

Код файла query_upd.php

```
<?php
        $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'arenda');
        if($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM records WHERE number > 2 ORDER BY `id` DESC")){
        while($set = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id = $set['id']; //поле из БД которое выводит ID
    echo '<div id="id_delete_div">Ваш ID='.$id.'<a href="" id="delete">Удалить</a><input id="id_rec" type="hidden" value="'.$id.'"></div>';
        }
        }
        ?>
```

По идее должно работать.

Есть другой способ, без AJAX, но выполнение скрипта на этой же странице:

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php
             $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'arenda');

            if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                $idd = $_GET['id'];
               mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `records` SET number = '1' WHERE id='$idd'");
            }

            ?>
        <?php

        if($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM records WHERE number > 2 ORDER BY `id` DESC")){
        while($set = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id = $set['id']; //поле из БД которое выводит ID
    echo '<div id="id_delete_div">Ваш ID='.$id.'<a href="?id='.$id.'" id="delete">Удалить</a><input id="id_rec" type="hidden" value="'.$id.'"></div>';
        }
        }
        ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Спасибо!

Comment: Если что то не так, пишите, постараюсь исправить

Comment: Мой сервер жалуется на открытые кавычки на 36 строке, после $(body).append("<?php, где if

Comment: Сейчас разберемся

Comment: Скобки, их должно быть 2, а там везде по одной. Закрывающие которые.

Comment: А почему не удаляются? Я жму по тексту, но ничего не происходит.

Comment: Попробуйте изменить в подключении к бд mysqli_connect - вставте свои данные типа: localhost, root, <пробел>, base

Comment: С подключением все отлично, выводятся мои ID. Но когда я жму кнопку удалить, ничего не происходит.

Comment: Все равно нет, как будто эти нажатия на "Удалить" не срабатывают

Comment: Проверил на локальном сервере XAMPP , все работает! попробуйте снова скопировать код, я его переделал

Comment: Может оно не правильно у меня как-то настроено ..( http://knocer.ru/testor.php

Comment: попробуйте новый код, все ошибки исправлены. Вы используете старый

Comment: Код - мечта. Один нюанс возник, если удаляю первую ссылку то все отлично, а если беру в центре любую, то не убирает

Comment: код работает но почему то  после нескольких удалений нужно обновить страницу. попробую разобраться

Comment: Все равно не убирает центральные, можете по ссылке посмотреть, только первый в списке

Comment: добавил без ajax, зато работает исправно

Comment: спасибо вам большое!